# Multiplying negatives = 2 Bediavads

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[If multiplying two negatives equals a positve](http://www.mathsisfun.com/multiplying-negatives.html) then shouldn't two Bedieveds equal a Lechatehila?

E.G. I heard from a HaRav Mansour Shelit"a that if one washes one's self with Tisha Kabin, then it counts for Mikwe Bediavad + HaRav Musafi Shelit"a writes in his book Shivat Sion that if one washes their hands with a Natlan 40 times (20 each) it counts as if one has Toveled in a Mikwe.

Do two Bediavads equal a Lechatehila?

(Please provide a complicated mathematical equation)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

Here's your forumla:

[image: Gravitational force]

You can use it to calculate the [gravity](http://www.universetoday.com/57713/gravity-formula/) of the act you are performing.